# Regex: Remove certain strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I know there is so many duplicates but I simply cannot find any previously asked regex question that is formatted like my question.

I have a big file with the following:

```
Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123:
```

I need to have a way to change it to go like:

```
Username123:MessageWithNoSpace123
```

and also like

```
email@gmail.com:MessageWithNoSpace123
```

So I need the Ip and the very last : removed.
How can I do this using Regular Expression in Notepad++

example:

```
Hellboy:hellboy@hotmail.com:11.111.11.11:Hey:
Samura:samura@hotmail.com:11.111.111.111:Sup:
```

Changed to:
Hellboy:Hey

```
samura@hotmail.com:sup
```

So like everything that was removed from the transition of the example to the change to i want removed. Get it now?

Comment: What do you mean and also like `email@gmail.com:MessageWithNoSpace123` ?

Comment: Step 1: simplify. Why bother with trying to find a single regexp? Replace `:$` with nothing to simplify the next step.

Comment: So like I need it to be formatted to be a username:message concept and then also be formatted to be a email:message concept.

Comment: What are the escaping rules?  For example, what if the username, email address or message contain `:` characters?

Comment: I wish to keep the second : after the email/username bit but i want the final one removed so a simple :$ wont cut it.

Comment: Eggyal I couldnt care less if the username or email address had it I couldnt care less if it was removed xD as long as this is fixed

Comment: So would `Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123:` become two separate lines with username/message followed by email/message?

Comment: Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123: Would become Username:message and I also need a seperate regex to output email:message

Comment: Why a separate regex to output email:message?

Comment: I need to have this txt file I got seperated and just formatted better and for documenting purposes. Just ocd u feel me

Answer (score 1):

Username123:MessageWithNoSpace123

```
\w+:\w+@\w+\.\w+
```

email@gmail.com:MessageWithNoSpace123

```
\w+:(\w+@\w+\.\w+):\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(:\w+):
```

Comment: Ok, I see that they find it fine, But in the usernames, they have spaces screwing this up, also i need it to somehow remove everything but the user:message not just highlight it

Comment: Also the email one doesnt work at all it just highlights the whole line including ip ranges etc

Comment: It works alright. You're just not using it right. You need to make use of the capture groups in the second regular expressions (in the brackets). Test it out here http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Also I dont actually need the username spaces to stay as spaces they can be removed. but im guessing a simple space in find and blank replace can sort that out

Comment: Also, you're talking about `highlighting` and `removing everything`. Highlighting is called matching and removing everything is called substitution. You can do both in notepad++.

Comment: Jvitasek, Can you provide me with regex to just remove the IP ranges, because none of this is actually working how u think it is because the username bit highlights the username perfectly but it also highlights the email. Can u provide me some way of properly ordering everything to make it user:message and email:message please?

Comment: Jvit, I get that but I need basically my whole list to be just changed from Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123: to Username123:MessageWithNoSpace123 and then I will seperately regex it to email@gmail.com:MessageWithNoSpace123 any ideas?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iS1fA5/1 -> Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123: to Username123:MessageWithNoSpace123

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sD2yF7/1 -> Username123:email@gmail.com:11.111.11.11:MessageWithNoSpace123: to email@gmail.com:MessageWithNoSpace123

Comment: Yeah but when I do that on Notepad++ on regular expression and replace as nothing it just removes the whole line =/

Comment: And from looking in the regex101 links I see that the : that should be inbetween user:msg and email:msg is removed =/

Comment: @JustinButler you explicitly told me you wanted this functionality. Not interested in chasing your question any further. Either provide real and definitive examples or good luck.

Comment: Made an example in op, Check it, Like I dont get how u dont understand what i need to be done lol

Comment: Sorry big noob!

    (\w+)\:\w+\@\w+\.\w+\.\w+\:(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\:(\w+)\:
    Replaced with \1:\3

Did the trick for the user:msg!
Only problem is that w is for word characters so emails with like john.doe@gmail.com didnt work :(